# What is best practice to run a custom function on specific values of an array of objects in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

Let's say I have two functions and an array of objects:

```
const f1 = (v) => {
   return v.toUpperCase();
}
const f2 = (v) => {
   return v.toLowerCase();
}
const arrayOfObjects = [
   {
      v1: "foo",
      v2: "bar",
      v3: "foobar",
   },
   {
      v1: "foo2",
      v2: "bar2",
      v3: "foobar2",
   },
   ...
];
```

How can I update my array and run `f1` on the `v1` property of each objects and `f2` on the `v2` property of each object?
In my real app, I'd like to format timestamps and usernames with this method.

Comment: Loop through the array and run your functions on the array element values?  What have you tried and what isn't working?

Comment: Are you looking for `forEach`, `for...of`, `map`? Do you want to mutate the properties in place or create new objects?

Comment: I'd go with forEach() unless async is needed but idk if that's "best practice"

Comment: There is no such thing as "best practice"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `map` method and some parameter destructuring.

```js
const arrayOfObjects = [{"v1":"foo","v2":"bar","v3":"foobar"},{"v1":"foo2","v2":"bar2","v3":"foobar2"}]
const f1 = (v) => v.toUpperCase();
const f2 = (v) => v.toLowerCase();

const result = arrayOfObjects
  .map(({ v1, v2, ...rest }) => ({
    ...rest,
    v1: f1(v1),
    v2: f2(v2)
  }))
  
console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 1):

ForEach will loop over your array.

```js
const f1 = (v) => {
   return v.toUpperCase();
}
const f2 = (v) => {
   return v.toLowerCase();
}
const arrayOfObjects = [
   {
      v1: "foo",
      v2: "bar",
      v3: "foobar",
   },
   {
      v1: "foo2",
      v2: "bar2",
      v3: "foobar2",
   }
];

arrayOfObjects.forEach(e => {
  e.v1 = f1(e.v1);
  e.v2 = f2(e.v2);
});

console.log(arrayOfObjects)
```

Answer (score -1):

You could use some regular expressions to dynamically look-up the associated function for the value.

Just locate the associated function by the index that appears at the end of the key.

```js
const funcMap = {
  f1: (v) => v.toUpperCase(),
  f2: (v) => v.toLowerCase(),
  f3: (v) => v.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + v.slice(1).toLowerCase()
};

const arr = [
  { v1: 'foo'  , v2: 'BAR'  , v3: 'foobar'  },
  { v1: 'foo2' , v2: 'BAR2' , v3: 'foobar2' }
];

const process = (arr) => {
  const funcEntries = Object.entries(funcMap);
  return arr.map(item => {
    const itemEntries = Object.entries(item);
    funcEntries.forEach(([funcKey, func]) => {
      const
        [ index ] = funcKey.match(/\d+$/),
        [ itemKey, itemValue ] = itemEntries
          .find(([ itemKey ]) =>
            itemKey.match(new RegExp(`${index}$`)));
      item[itemKey] = func(itemValue);
    });
    return item;
  });
};

console.log(process(arr));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { top: 0; max-height: 100% !important; }
```